# Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan (On Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, kinect, ros

I want to connect my microsoft kinect 360 with ROS on my Raspberry Pi3b. I've already installed Ubuntu and Ros on the Device. I follow the instructions on this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOUjvwyRz9U.

At the installation part

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan
```

I get this Error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` before that

Answer (score 0):

Install rosdep and run `rosdep update`